# Definition: smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing a random variable

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $I$ be an index set, $\{Y_i: i \in I\}$ a collection of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ and $\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ a countable collection of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$.

In my understanding, given $Y_i: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, $\sigma(Y_i) = \{ Y^{-1}(B): B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that $Y_i$ is a random variable. However, an exercise asks me to prove that
\begin{align}
\sigma\{Y_i: i \in I\} = \sigma\{ Y_i^{-1}(B): i \in I, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\},
\end{align}
which is (according to me) trivial. Is this true?

Comment: Seems more like a definition to me...

Comment: The answer could be found in this posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195648/sigma-algebra-of-collection-of-random-variables?rq=1