# Random variables: algebra to $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, random-variables

Let $\{ X_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ be a countable collection of random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$. Let $\mathcal{X}_n = \sigma\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{A} = \cup_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{X}_n$.

It could be shown that $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra. However, I would like to show as well that
\begin{align}
(*) \qquad \sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \sigma\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}. 
\end{align} 
Therefore, we have to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under taking the union over $\mathbb{N}$. However, I do not see how to make the transition from the algebra property towards taking the union over $n \in \mathbb{N}$ in the sense of equation $(*)$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Therefore, we have to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under taking the union over $\mathbb{N}$" This is not at all what you are supposed to show, and is in fact false in general. Note that $(\ast)$ does not state that $$\mathcal{A} = \sigma\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$ but that $$\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \sigma\{X_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

Comment: The answer could be found in this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195648/sigma-algebra-of-collection-of-random-variables?rq=1